# check if object has been declared in objective c

Tags: objective-c, allocation

is it possible to check if an object is declared?

e.g.

```
if(object) {    
   //object is known 
} else
{    
    int object; 
}
```

if I do it like this I'm getting the error "use of undeclared identifier 'object'"

Comment: You can wrap stuff in pre-processor ifs and stuff like that. See the .pch file in your project.

Comment: This actually does not make any sense, it is part of programming to know these things. If methods are small (8-10 lines in general) there is little room to be confused, If there is confusion the code is un-clear and should be re-writen.

Comment: The problem is that it's a massive project and I would have to rewrite the whole structure. I know that there are many better ways but that would mean too much effort for a little issue.

Comment: If the problem is badly written code adding a bad fix will just make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold an empty pointer, and initialize it when you need it.

```
id object = nil;
.... some stuff here
if (!object) {
    object = [SomeClass new];
}

.... your job with that object
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is checking that the object has been instantiated. It isn't checking that the object has been declared. In fact, you are declaring the object in the first line.

Comment: Actually even the `= nil` is not needed, all objects are now set to nil in Objective-C.

Comment: @Zaph it's actually for demonstration purposes

Comment: @Fogmeister I think, there is no actually purpose to save 4/8 bytes and do not declare that pointer, as the code that will handle that case will cost more memory.